# Creating map from list, where key is in part of inner and outer object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible (in simple way) to change it into `java8` `Stream`? (Please do not comment/answer if you want to tell me that two `for` are better and not all loops should be changed to streams, it's not a point)

```
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

for(final Person person: list) {
    for(final Internal internal: person.getInternals()) {
        final String key = person.getName() + internal.getKey();
        map.put(key, internal.getValue());
    }
}
```

The main problem is that I can't use `flatMap` because I will lose previous information. **Each created `key` is unique.**

Comment: you do not need second loop at all, as it is the same as: for each person, put its name and last internal value to the map. You can do this in grouping collector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could pass those along via a `Pair` (I have not compiled this though, but the idea should be there)

```
 list.stream()
    .flatMap(person -> person.getInternals()
                       .stream()
                       .map(internal -> 
                           Pair.of(person.getName() + internal.getKey(), internal.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getLeft, Pair::getRight));
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, that using another object is an answer here, but in this solution we need second internal stream. I hope there is an answer with one chain

Comment: @ByeBye how would you get rid of the second iteration? I don't get you at all right now

Comment: @ByeBye this *is* “one chain”

Comment: I mean like `flatMap` on internals, but with getting additonal field from outer class

Comment: @ByeBye this makes no sense... sorry, I don't get it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collect` directly and if you are sure that each created key is unique, as you mentioned, the accumulator and combiner are simple to write:

```
Map<String, String> map =
    list.stream().collect(HashMap::new,
                          (m, p) -> p.getInternals().forEach(i -> m.put(p.getName() + i.getKey(), i.getValue())),
                          Map::putAll);
```